# How to leave a timestamp field empty?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a problem. I'm trying to return into my 'date' field either a timestamp (fetched from another column) or an empty value when finding an specific value in another field.
For example, display the timestamp into my 'DATE' field only if 'ACTION TAKEN' = 'CANCELLED', else, leave the 'DATE' field empty.

[image: Example here]

This is the query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS INVESTIGATIVE_ACTION_TABLE;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE INVESTIGATIVE_ACTION_TABLE AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.POLICY_NBR AS POLICY_ID, 
        TRANS_TYP_DESC AS ACTION_TAKEN, 
        CNCL_EFCTV_DT AS CANCEL_EFECT_DATE,
  
    FROM POLICY_DETAILS AS t1
    INNER JOIN CANC_EFCTV AS t2
    ON t1.POLICY_NBR = t2.POLICY_NBR
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY POLICY_ID, ACTION_TAKEN, CANCEL_EFECT_DATE
    ORDER BY POLICY_ID DESC) = 1
    ORDER BY POLICY_ID DESC
);
```

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. Edit your question to add details, or it might be closed.

Comment: CANCEL_EFECT_DATE : convert datatime to varchar datatype. When ACTION TAKEN' = 'CANCELLED', leave blank to this field.

Comment: `case when ACTION_TAKEN = 'CANCELLED' then DATE else null end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be returning NULL for the non-cancelled records. Can you try this one?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE INVESTIGATIVE_ACTION_TABLE AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.POLICY_NBR AS POLICY_ID, 
        TRANS_TYP_DESC AS ACTION_TAKEN, 
        IFF(TRANS_TYP_DESC = 'CANCELLED', CNCL_EFCTV_DT, NULL) AS CANCEL_EFECT_DATE
    FROM POLICY_DETAILS AS t1
    INNER JOIN CANC_EFCTV AS t2
    ON t1.POLICY_NBR = t2.POLICY_NBR
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY POLICY_ID, ACTION_TAKEN, CANCEL_EFECT_DATE
    ORDER BY POLICY_ID DESC) = 1
    ORDER BY POLICY_ID DESC
);
```

IFF: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html